# Check if a time range falls between an other time range

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have to check if a time range falls between an other one. For instance, I've got the time range **08:00 -> 10:00** and an other which is 10:00 -> 13:00 and I have to check if these two fall between **11:00 -> 12:00**. Here below is what I'm doing and still not working :

```
if (startTime >= ci.StartTime && endTime <= ci.EndTime)
{
    //some code
}
```

The start and end time is my initial time range and the ci's start and end time is the time range from which I'm doing the checking. Any idea guys?

Comment: What is the problem with it?

Comment: Whether they fall between or have an intersection? How many time spans do you have? Two or many?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but something that might be useful if you have a lot of such time things to do in your app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. I don't think it gets any more concise than this.

```
if (startTime <= ci.EndTime && endTime >= ci.StartTime)
{
    //some code
}
```